# How to delete lines from a variable line number to the last line?

Tags: bash, sed

In bash, I defined a variable n, from which value of line number to the last line is what I am going to delete.

I tried

```
sed -i '${n},$d' file
```

but the error msg is:

sed: -e expression #1, char 5: extra characters after command

Any thoughts about how to correct the use of sed? I suspect it is because of two $ in the sed, one is for variable, the other is for the last line number.

Comment: `${n}` won't be expanded within single quotes.

Comment: `sed -i $n',$d' file`

Comment: sed -i "${n},$d" test 
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unexpected `,'

Comment: Thanks, miken32. It works!

Comment: I am wondering why putting $n outside ' ' works?

Comment: @LeiZhang because [shell expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) doesn't happen inside single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 1):

For portability, clarity, and safety, the following would be reasonable:

```
sed -i.bak -e "${n},\$d" file
```